# What does the -1 in this SQL line do?

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to figure out how to translate a line of code from SQL to Python. The LEAD function I get. The problem is I don't understand what the -1 does:

```
cast(LEAD(table1.Date_A,1,null) over (partition by table1.Column1 order by table1.Date_A asc)-1 as date)
```

Comment: SQL Server allows you to add and subtract numbers from datetime. +1 adds a day to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

It subtracts "1" from the result of the `lead()`.

What it does depends on the type of `date_a`.  In many databases, subtracting `1` from a date/time data type subtracts one day.

That is not true of all databases.  And if `date_a` is of a different type, then it could be arithmetic subtraction.